# Keycloak create realm by sharding

Tags: keycloak

Is it possible to create a two separate clusters of Keycloak and shard realm creation by name?

Eg:

Cluster A - Keycloak instance1,...instance3

Cluster B - Keycloak instance1,...instance3

```
if hashCode(realm1)%2 == 0 
  create realm in cluster A
else
   create realm in cluster B
```

Comment: But these two cluster will be connect to the same DB (Even DB also in Cluster ),So what is the advantage ?

Comment: Keycloak setup is not scalable if we create more than 400 realms. My thought is like horizontally scaling the keycloak and create realms in different clusters with individual DB for cluster. Is there any other approach to make keycloak Scalable.
[Thanks for the reply.]

Comment: @sreekesh.s did you manage to do this?